# How can I get rid of this in a MAC

Tags: osx-yosemite

I'm trying to compile apache http from source I have done this:

```
export CC=gcc
export CPP=cpp
```

but I'm getting this when I run make:

```
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool: line 8962: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
```

What can I do? I don't know why it's calling cc instead of gcc as per the commands above and cc does exist anyway.

Thanks

Comment: Did you install Xcode?

Comment: Yes I did with its command line tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that cc is actually at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/ so I ran:

```
ln -s XcodeDefault.xctoolchain OSX10.10.xctoolchain
```

And that fixed it.